# i run this code but it donot type the array

Tags: php, for-loop, multidimensional-array

```
  $studentArray =  array(
    array("ahmed2",15,3.5),
    array("ahmed1",15,2.4),
    array("ahmed3",29,3.9),
    array("ahmed4",22,3),
    array("ahmed5",23,2.8)
  );
  foreach($studentArray as $key => $value ){
        echo $key. '-'.$value.'<br>'; 
  }
```

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve here. You have a two-dimensional array, but you act like it's a key-value based array (which is actually a map).

Comment: I'm not sure what your question/problem is. Can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Your problem is array to string conversion. `$value` is an array, and arrays can't be echoed.

Comment: i want to print each index in array in aseparated line and this message appear "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\lamia\index.php on line 74
1-Array" @MCEmperor

Comment: What El_Vanja said. Your array is two-dimensional, so each element is in turn a one-dimensional array. Echoing an array yields the string "`Array`".

Comment: You will need a nested `foreach` (one inside the other).

Comment: Please edit your question to contain more details about what you want to achieve, what the code currently does, and what you've tried to resolve the problem

Comment: thanks i run the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have student detail array in **$studentArray**, you need an extra foreach to loop through inner array.

Try below code in your structure.

```
    $studentArray =  array(
        array("ahmed2",15,3.5),
        array("ahmed1",15,2.4),
        array("ahmed3",29,3.9),
        array("ahmed4",22,3),
        array("ahmed5",23,2.8)
    );
    foreach($studentArray as $studentDetail ){
        foreach($studentDetail as $key => $value ){
            echo $key. '-'.$value.'<br>';
        }
    }
```

For more better understanding, have a try with below code.

```
    $studentArray =  array(
        array("val1"=>"ahmed2","val2"=>15,"val3"=>3.5),
        array("val1"=>"ahmed1","val2"=>15,"val3"=>2.4),
        array("val1"=>"ahmed3","val2"=>29,"val3"=>3.9),
        array("val1"=>"ahmed4","val2"=>22,"val3"=>3),
        array("val1"=>"ahmed5","val2"=>23,"val3"=>2.8)
    );
    
    foreach($studentArray as $student){
        foreach($student as $key => $value) { 
            echo $key. '-'.$value.'<br>';
        }
        echo '<br>';
    }
```